# Given a data frame with many columns, is there a way two loop through only two of the columns?

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

Given a data frame with the columns id, name, rating, purchase, spending. Let's say I wanted to loop through the rating and spending columns at the same time, so in the same loop. How would I go about doing so? One idea I thought of was creating a smaller data frame with only those two columns and loop through that, but I figured it would be nice to know how to take a data frame as a whole and loop through specific columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) with subset:

`Series` as output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
                   'name':[4,5,6],
                   'rating':[7,8,9],
                   'purchase':[1,3,5],
                   'spending':[5,3,6]})

print (df)
   id  name  purchase  rating  spending
0   1     4         1       7         5
1   2     5         3       8         3
2   3     6         5       9         6

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print (row[['rating','spending']])

rating      7
spending    5
Name: 0, dtype: int64
rating      8
spending    3
Name: 1, dtype: int64
rating      9
spending    6
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

---

```
for idx, row in df[['rating','spending']].iterrows():
    print (row)

rating      7
spending    5
Name: 0, dtype: int64
rating      8
spending    3
Name: 1, dtype: int64
rating      9
spending    6
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

Scalar output - `iterrows` or [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print (row["rating"])
    print (row["spending"])

7
5
8
3
9
6              

for row in df.itertuples():
    print (row.rating)
    print (row.spending)

7
5
8
3
9
6
```

Answer (score 3):

use `itertuples`

```
for r, s in df[['rating','spending']].itertuples(index=False):
    print(r, s)

7 5
8 3
9 6
```

---

Borrowing @jezrael's setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
                   'name':[4,5,6],
                   'rating':[7,8,9],
                   'purchase':[1,3,5],
                   'spending':[5,3,6]})

print (df)
   id  name  purchase  rating  spending
0   1     4         1       7         5
1   2     5         3       8         3
2   3     6         5       9         6
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pythonic way for looping through 2 columns:

```
for rating, spending in zip(df["rating"],df["spending"]):
    print (rating, spending)
```

In case you are using python2:

```
from itertools import izip
for rating, spending in izip(df["rating"],df["spending"]):
    print (rating, spending)
```

This is the pandas way for looping through:

```
for _,row in df.iterrows():
    print (row["rating"],row["spending"])
```